# How to fix "error: no previous declaration for void awn::vala_array_destroy"?

Tags: c++

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 32 platform. I'm trying to compile awn with latest vala. I get following error message.

```
vala-utils.cc: In function 'void awn::vala_array_destroy(gpointer, gint, GDestroyNotify)':
vala-utils.cc:358:6: error: no previous declaration for 'void   awn::vala_array_destroy(gpointer, gint, GDestroyNotify)' [-Werror=missing-declarations]
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Looks to me as if the declaration is parsed as a _call_ by the compiler (so that it complains about calling an unknown function). Unless you have edited the file or one of its headers, the only reason I could imagine is a faulty define through configure or on the make or g++ command line. Since make evaluates the environment, the ultimate culprit could also be there.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: <strike>Looks more like a member function definition with no matching member function declaration in the class definition body.</strike> I checked the source and it's not a member function.

Comment: What version of "Awn"? (Saying "the latest" is totally useless) Any other errors? What was the command you used? Be _precise_.

Comment: detail info is here http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/avant-window-navigator-gets-new.html

Comment: here are the links of the source packages 
https://github.com/p12tic/awn
https://github.com/p12tic/awn-extras
https://github.com/p12tic/libdesktop-agnostic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of `vala-utils.cc` insert the function prototype:

`void vala_array_destroy(gpointer array, gint array_length, GDestroyNotify destroy_func);`

This will silence the warning which is causing the build to fail due to `-Werror` defined in the Makefile. Consider raising a pull request for the benefit of the maintainers.

Alternatively modify ln.89 in `configure.ac` and remove the `-Werror` to stop the warning failing the build.

Comment: I'm sorry that you think that, it's sad when accusations get thrown around like that. Would you prefer it if I deleted my answer?

Answer (score 3):

This actually a *warning*, and a rather pedantic one at that.

It's saying that the global function `awn::vala_array_destroy` has not been declared beforehand. Usually this is a sign of a programmer's mistake, but from [the source](https://github.com/p12tic/awn/blob/master/libawn/vala-utils.cc) it seems to me that:

1. this function is only supposed to be used by `awn::vala_array_free` directly below it (in which case it should really have been given internal linkage), *or*
2. a declaration is available in some header elsewhere (in which case it's probably in the *wrong* header, as it ought to be in [vala-utils.h](https://github.com/p12tic/awn/blob/master/libawn/vala-utils.h)).

The long and short of it is that the code is *probably* fine, if a little strangely designed. This case is being treated as an error because you have `-Werror` turned on for this warning, turning it into an error.

I don't know how you're building the library, but you could adjust the compiler flags to avoid this; by default, GCC does *not* emit this warning, nor turn it into an error. Alternatively, you could add the function declaration into vala-utils.h yourself. You should also take up the issue with the library's maintainers.

**Update:** I found the culprit on line 89 of AWN's [configure.ac](https://github.com/p12tic/awn/blob/master/configure.ac). You should definitely take this up with the library maintainers. I'd be amazed if this had not already been reported as a bug; I believe it was introduced in [this revision](https://github.com/p12tic/awn/commit/0ac173a711c5742d9f1043bdd9ebeb86f236c01f).

Comment: I am grateful to both of you for answers. Yours seems to be more helpful

Comment: I accepted his answer because I saw his answer a few seconds earlier than your answer.

Comment: Too bad I wrote mine almost ten minutes earlier. \*Sigh\* Oh well

Comment: I know you deserved that, but I must keep my self-esteem because I really saw his post earlier.

Comment: For what it's worth, the function declaration does not belong in vala-utils.h. This function is private to the translation unit.

Comment: @fixxxer: What makes you say that? I don't inherently disagree, but unless you composed that code I don't see how you could know either way? Anyway, if this is the case, then it should have internal linkage. I did cover both scenarios in my answer.